# permission denied, cannot list files within a folder

Tags: centos, ls

I have a folder like:

```
drwx--xrwx  9 user group 4096 May  1 11:17 160429_ST-E00110_0195_AHMFVNCCXX
```

However my user ***other*** can't do ls:

```
-bash-4.1$ ls 160429_ST-E00110_0195_AHMFVNCCXX
ls: cannot open directory 160429_ST-E00110_0195_AHMFVNCCXX: Permission denied
```

***other*** is neither member of the group nor owner of the files

I thought that the last 3 bits describes the permission for any other user

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Is `other` member of `group`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, other is neither member of the group nor owner of the files

Comment: What are the permissions on each parent directory of that directory? Also, `selinux`, or possibly those POSIX-acls-that-are-not-POSIX, though that usually fancies up the `ls` listing.

Comment: @thrig Since the user seems to have cd'ed to the parent directory, he apparently has appropriate permissions to it.

Comment: @Barmar the user could arrive to that working directory via a `su`, or could have done the `cd` before permissions where changed. However, that does change the error message. Though, I still prefer to audit the full path regardless.

Comment: I suspect the user really is a member of the group. Maybe it's one of their secondary groups. What does the `id` command say?

Comment: Is NFS involved?